# JQuery - click and hover on same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-hover

I have this jQuery script:

```
$('img[data-hover]').hover(function() {
    $(this)
        .attr('tmp', $(this).attr('src'))
        .attr('src', $(this).attr('data-hover'))
        .attr('data-hover', $(this).attr('tmp'))
        .removeAttr('tmp');
}).each(function() {
    $('<img />').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-hover'));

});
```

It works fine, when I hove the images, the hover works fine.

But now I need to start the hover again, when I click on certain boxes, on those:

```
$('#first, #second, #third').click(function(){  .....
```

Is it somehow possible to start the hover "on click" and keep the actual hover function? Or even modify it to a "function"?

I've tried it but I failed.
Thanks.

EDIT:
here's the HTML code with the images:

```
<div class="auswahlbox">
        <div class="auswahl" id="first" data-id="1">
            <div class="bild">
                <img src="https://image.jpg" data-hover="https://images_hover.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="auswahl" id="second" data-id="2">
            <div class="bild">
                <img src="https://image.jpg" data-hover="https://images_hover.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="auswahl" id="third" data-id="3">
            <div class="bild">
                <img src="https://image.jpg" data-hover="https://images_hover.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Situation now:**
When I hove the images in .bild it works fine.

**What I need:**
When I click the `"<div class="auswahl" id="first" data-id="1">"` (second, third) div, the hover of the images shall "start" once.

Comment: "`#first, #second, #third`" means you have also 3 images? Or you want to activate the "hover" on all your images?

Comment: Without html code, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$('#first, #second, #third').click(function(){
    $('img[data-hover]').trigger('mouseover');
});
```

When `#first, #second #third` are clicked it triggers the hover event on `img[data-hover]`.

To just trigger images in the same `div` try:

```
$('#first, #second, #third').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img[data-hover]').trigger('mouseover');
});
```

Comment: This is good. something like this. But what I forgot to mention is, that I need to start the hover on the same images as in the function before. I add the code in a few minutes.

Comment: yes, the hover itself works, but the trigger isn't. I got an another function that works in those boxes.  http://pastebin.com/a2pJfsiu

Comment: yes, it works... very good indeed but on all pictures. Is it possible to trigger just the picture in the same "div" ?

Comment: I just added a variation of the `click` event which will only target the images within the clicked div.